# Android Studio 2.1 very slow build, macbook blows very loud

Tags: macos, android

I am using new version of Android Studio since one week (v2.1) and it completely freezes my macbook. Each gradle build takes forever, and my computer blows air like if it is going to die.

Anyone experiencing issues of this kind ?

OS X El Capitan 10.11.2 core i7, 16 ram GBB

Comment: Normal behavior would be my guess. Compiling takes resources, and as a result. Your MacBook is simply cooling itself down whilst under load.

Comment: Yeah but with the previous version of Android Studio, it wasn't slow at all...

Comment: Same here. AS 2.1 is worse than the previous version.

Comment: Yeah, worse than any other version imao

Comment: Same issue. .. Its worse after updated Studio to 2.1.. Did all the tricks but its taking atleast 3 minutes ti run a release build...

Comment: I did not changed anything and it is working fine now. Does AS has auto update feature ?

Answer (score -2):

Android 2.1.1 is available, I have updated studio from 2.1.0 to 2.1.1 and works.
On studio 2.1.0 I was facing same problem.